# Foundation 6.4.1 - Bootstrap .container equivalent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

What is the Bootstrap .container equivalent now in Foundation 6.4.1?

It used to be .row in 6.3.1. But it does not work in that way anymore in 6.4.1:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  content
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

6.3.1:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  content
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 6.4 uses a new grid system called XY Grid according to their [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html).

The equivalent appears to be `grid-container`.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell small-4">cell</div>
    <div class="cell small-4">cell</div>
    <div class="cell small-4">cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!